# Best way to compute 3-hourly variances of NARR Geopotential Height Data and Save Results to Disk

Tags: python-xarray, netcdf4

**INTRODUCTION**

I need to compute the variance of the 3-hourly geopotential height (gph) data hosted by NOAA's Physical Science Laboratory (https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.narr.html).  PSL-NARR offers the 3-hourly mean Geopotential Heights; however, to compare means (for instance the mean 850mb gph for Day1 to that for Day2) really requires some information about the population variances for the two days.

**PROBLEM**

So far I have been unsuccessful in saving any computation results to a local disk file.  I am providing a slimmed-down example which captures the essence of my problem, while running (and failing) in a reasonable amount of time.

```
import datetime as dt
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message = r"variable 'hgt' has multiple fill values") 

#  Specify a set of files (5 of the 535 files that define the full dataset to be accessed
files = ['https://psl.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/NARR/pressure/hgt.197901.nc',
 'https://psl.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/NARR/pressure/hgt.197902.nc',
 'https://psl.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/NARR/pressure/hgt.197903.nc',
 'https://psl.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/NARR/pressure/hgt.197904.nc',
 'https://psl.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/NARR/pressure/hgt.197905.nc']

# Open the datasets using xarray's open_mfdataset function.

test = xr.open_mfdataset(files,chunks='auto')

# Select one level and compute the standard deviation across the
# time dimension.

# In practice, the data for each day at a given 3-hourly interval
# will be used to compute the std. dev., but that level of 
# complexity is not needed for this example.

test1 = test.sel(level=1000).std(dim='time')

# trying test.load() first makes no difference in the result. 
test1.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

Inspecting the "result" of the computation looks reasonable:

[image: Contents of test1]

But writing to disk fails after about 10 minutes, with the following error traceback.  (NOTE: this traceback was generated by running a script from the command line, while the image of the xarray.Dataset description is from the same script in a Jupyter Notebook output.)

```
  File "/Users/gdl/MetPy/OpenDAP_test.py", line 16, in <module>                                                                 
    test.to_netcdf('test.nc')                                                                                                   
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1957, in to_netcdf    
    return to_netcdf(  # type: ignore  # mypy cannot resolve the overloads:(                                                    
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1281, in to_netcdf    
    writes = writer.sync(compute=compute)                                                                                       
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 178, in sync       
    delayed_store = chunkmanager.store(                                                                                         
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/daskmanager.py", line 211, in store     
    return store(                                                                                                               
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 89, in get                  
    results = get_async(                                                                                                        
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 511, in get_async              
    raise_exception(exc, tb)                                                                                                    
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 319, in reraise                
    raise exc                                                                                                                   
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 224, in execute_task           
    result = _execute_task(task, data)                                                                                          
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 484, in __array__    
    return np.asarray(self.get_duck_array(), dtype=dtype)                                                                       
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 487, in get_duck_array                                                                                                                               
    return self.array.get_duck_array()                                                                                          
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 664, in get_duck_array                                                                                                                               
    return self.array.get_duck_array()                                                                                          
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 557, in get_duck_array                                                                                                                               
    array = array.get_duck_array()                                                                                              
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/coding/variables.py", line 74, in get_duck_array                                                                                                                             
    return self.func(self.array.get_duck_array())                                                                               
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 551, in get_duck_array                                                                                                                               
    array = self.array[self.key]                                                                                                
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 100, in __getitem__                                                                                                                                  return indexing.explicit_indexing_adapter(
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 858, in explicit_indexing_adapter
    result = raw_indexing_method(raw_key.tuple)
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 113, in _getitem
    array = getitem(original_array, key)
  File "/Users/gdl/opt/anaconda3/envs/MetPy_x86/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 73, in robust_getitem
    return array[key]
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 4739, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 5688, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1965, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
RuntimeError: NetCDF: DAP failure
```

From my research, this failure seems to occur when the volume of data being processed is just too large. Perhaps what I am trying to do is not possible, given the about of data I am trying to process.

Answer (score 0):

After running some timing tests, I found the following:

TEST:  compute means and standard deviations for the 3 heights (1000mb, 850mb, 700mb) for a given day and hour.

- The time it takes for xarray's *open_mfdataset* to construct a dataset of 45 remote files on the PSL server is 59.5 seconds.  This does not include the time it would take to save the means and standard deviations, which operation I have so far failed to achieve.
- Using the *netCDF4* package, the time it takes to compute the means and standard deviations of 3 heights for the same 45 remote files is 70.5 seconds.  This is not a significant difference in time, given I have not succeeded in getting the *open_mfdataset* process to run successfully.

Therefore, unless someone can advise me on a method to speed up the *open_mfdataset* process so that xarray is faster, using the *netCDF4* package is so far the "Best Way" to compute the 3-hourly variance data I need.

Here is the code I am currently testing and optimizing.  Suggestions for improvement are *very* welcome.

```
#  File:  NARR_HMS_v1.py
#  Run as:
#  python NARR_HMS_v1.py Month Day Hour

from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
import sys
from os.path import exists

import warnings
#. ignore warnings when nanmean or nanstd operate on all NaN
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message = 'Mean of empty slice')
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message = 'Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice')

#. Set up some constants
#. Days in Month, offset so base 1:  January is Month #1 not Month #0
DaysInMonth=[np.nan,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

Month = int(sys.argv[1])
strMonth = str(Month)
if (Month<10):strMonth = '0'+strMonth

Day = int(sys.argv[2])
strDay = str(Day)
if Day<10:strDay = '0'+strDay

Hour = int(sys.argv[3])
if (Hour % 3 != 0):
    print('Can only process 3-hourly data.')
    quit()
strHour = str(Hour)
if (Hour<10):strHour = '0'+strHour

#  Check to see if we have already computed the data set , and  quit if we have.
OutFile = '/Users/gdl/MetPy/NARR/' + 'HMS_' + strMonth + strDay + strHour + '.nc'
if (exists(OutFile)):
    print('Requested analysis file already exists in NARR directory.  Exiting....')
    quit()

#. set up paths to files on server
cat = TDSCatalog('https://psl.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/Datasets/NARR/pressure/catalog.xml')
opendap_url = cat.datasets[0].access_urls['OPENDAP']
base_url = opendap_url.split(str(cat.datasets[0]))[0]

#. get height file names
file_names = [f for f in cat.datasets if f.split('.')[0]=='hgt']

#. select subset of filenames for "Month" in each year available and add base url.
#.  xfiles = the set of file names
#.  file_urls = set of complete URLs for each file in xfiles
xfiles = [f for f in file_names if f.split('.')[1][-2:]==strMonth]
file_urls = [base_url+f for f in xfiles]

#  pre-allocate data arrays for 1000mb, 850mb, 700mb with NaN

xdim = 349
ydim = 277
h1000 = np.full((len(xfiles),ydim,xdim),np.nan)
h850 = np.full((len(xfiles),ydim,xdim),np.nan)
h700 = np.full((len(xfiles),ydim,xdim),np.nan)

#. build array for "Month, Day" heights for 1000,850,700mb at "Hour"
for i in np.arange(len(xfiles)):
    dataset = netCDF4.Dataset(file_urls[i])

    #. we can't assume the files all have the same number of days in month or reports per level per day
    #. even though the idea of "reanalysis" implies a clean dataset
    time_var = dataset['time']
    dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var,time_var.units,only_use_cftime_datetimes=False)

    Yrs = np.array([t.year for t in dtime])
    Mos = np.array([t.month for t in dtime])
    Dys = np.array([t.day for t in dtime])
    Hrs = np.array([t.hour for t in dtime])

    HourList = np.intersect1d(np.where(Mos==Month),np.where(Dys==Day))
    HourIndex = HourList[np.where(Hrs[HourList]==Hour)]

    h1000[i,:,:] = dataset['hgt'][HourIndex,0,:,:].filled(fill_value=np.nan)
    h850[i,:,:] = dataset['hgt'][HourIndex,6,:,:].filled(fill_value=np.nan)
    h700[i,:,:] = dataset['hgt'][HourIndex,12,:,:].filled(fill_value=np.nan)
    if (i==0):
        lons = np.array(dataset['lon'])
        lats = np.array(dataset['lat'])
    dataset.close()

#. compute means (M*) and standard deviations (S*) for all (lon,lat)
M1000 = np.nanmean(h1000,axis=0)
S1000 = np.nanstd(h1000,axis=0)
M850 = np.nanmean(h850,axis=0)
S850 = np.nanstd(h850,axis=0)
M700 = np.nanmean(h850,axis=0)
S700 = np.nanstd(h850,axis=0)

#. convert to Dataset
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars=dict(M1000=(['y','x'], M1000),S1000=(['y', 'x'], S1000),
                               M850=(['y','x'], M850),S850=(['y', 'x'], S850),
                               M700=(['y','x'], M700),S700=(['y', 'x'], S700)),
                coords=dict(lon=(['y', 'x'],lons) ,lat=(['y', 'x'], lats)))

#. write to disk
ds.to_netcdf(OutFile)
```